# Make a synchronous call using Node.js and Express for Action on Google?

Tags: node.js, express, actions-on-google

I am running a Node.js Server with Express to interface with Actions on Google. To fulfill a request I need to hit an external server so I am using the Fetch library. I cannot seem to get the node server to wait for the web service call to give the appropriate response. I've tried using Promises and Await/Async but I have not implemented it correctly.. can someone please help make this work? Thank you!

```
let fetch = require('node-fetch');
let express = require('express');
let bodyParser = require('body-parser');
let { dialogflow, Image } = require('actions-on-google');
let app = dialogflow();
let json;

function middleware(req,res,next) {
    json = req.body;
    next();
}

app.intent('StartIntent', conv => async function() {
    const response = await communicate(json);
    console.log(response);
    // Not running synchronously
    conv.ask('Need the response from above');
});

function communicate( message ) {
    let response;
    try {
        response = fetch('https://stackoverflow.com', {
            method: 'POST',
            body:   JSON.stringify(message),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
        });
        return response;
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
        return null;
    }
}

express().use(bodyParser.json(), middleware, app).listen(3000);
```

@Prisoner is correct - conv.ask() should only be called once the json data from the result of communicate() is returned. However, the only thing that is being returned in a Promise object at that point. The data is being retrieved correctly as a json object.

```
let fetch = require('node-fetch');
let express = require('express');
let bodyParser = require('body-parser');
let { dialogflow, Image } = require('actions-on-google');
let app = dialogflow();
let json;

function middleware(req,res,next) {
    json = req.body;
    next();
}

app.intent('StartIntent', conv => {
    const response = communicate(json);
    console.log("StartIntent Response:");
    console.log(response); // output: Promise { <pending> }
    // Not running synchronously :(
    console.log(response.text);
    conv.ask('Need the response from above');
});

function communicate( message ) {
    let response;
    try {
        response = fetch('https://google.com', {
            method: 'POST',
            body:   JSON.stringify(message),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
        }).then(function(body) {
            return body.json();
        }).then(function(json) {
            // The data is returning successfully
            // For example: {"BTCUSD":10000}
            return json;
        }).catch(function() {
            // error handling
        });
        return response; // This is returning a pending Promise
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
        return null;
    }
}

express().use(bodyParser.json(), middleware, app).listen(3006);
```

Comment: This setup won't work. What is `app.intent`? Is that a custom function you've added to the main `app` instance? Or is that supposed to be an endpoint?

Comment: `app.intent()` is registering an Actions on Google Intent handler. It will be called as part of the express handling, and that looks like it should work correctly, why do you think it won't work? I think they're trying to say that `conv.ask()` needs to be called only when they get the response from the call to `communicate()`, but that it doesn't seem to be working as expected.

Comment: Farr East - what is `communicate()` returning? Have you confirmed that it is a Promise that resolves to what you expect it to?

Comment: @Prisoner `communicate()` does fetch the result I am looking for within the last `.then()` callback. Anything outside of this function will return a pending Promise. The `conv` callback cannot be an async function as originally attempted it seems. Google returns an error.

Comment: @Prisoner If I attempt to `await` the `communicate()` function Google says: `No response has been set. Is this being used in an async call that was not returned as a promise to the intent handler?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fetch()` returns a Promise. You can chain a `then()` call for `communicate()`, and use the response for `conv.ask()` in the body.

Here's a simple example code snippet using node-fetch to make an API call and use the response from that call. (Note this example is performing a GET request on JSON data.)

```javascript
'use strict';

const { dialogflow } = require('actions-on-google');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

const app = dialogflow({debug: true});

// Default Welcome Intent
app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', (conv) => {
  return apiCall().then((response) => {
    conv.ask(`Response from above ${JSON.stringify(response)}`);
  });
});

// Makes an API call to a URL to retrieve JSON data.
function apiCall() {
  const URL = 'https://example.com/data.json';
  return fetch(URL).then((response) => response.json());
}

exports.endpoint = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Comment: Thank you @Taylor Caldwell! That works like a charm.

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help. :)